# Why is the SideBarRoute not found in SidebarElements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, create-react-app

I'm building a website via react-app and I'm stuck on an error:

https://github.com/TheShappix44/React-website

this is a sample of my code without the package json and some other files.
The error message is the following:
"" Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/components/Sidebar/index.js 56:39-51

export 'SideBarRoute' (imported as 'SideBarRoute') was not found in './SidebarElements' (possible exports: CloseIcon, Icon, SideBtnWrap, SidebarContainer, SidebarLink, SidebarMenu, SidebarRoute, SidebarWrapper) ""

Comment: Looks like spelling mistake. In your index.js, you have called **SideBarRoute** component but your SidebarElements has defined **SidebarRoute** which has small letter **b**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **SidebarRoute** to **SideBarRoute** in your SidebarElements.js file with capital **B** for **bar**.